# Can't install ubuntu on my computer!

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

I can't install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my DELL Inspiron 15. It only detects the bootable Ubuntu USB pen drive I'm using:[image: cant install ubuntu.]

The bootable pen drive I'm using is 8GB. My internal hard drive is 500GB.

Comment: Without more information, I'd look in the BIOS to see if there's a setting to enable AHCI. It's often an option listed as "Intel RST" or similar. Enable AHCI and then see if the installer recognizes your internal disk.

Comment: AHCI is already enabled by default.

Comment: Are the expected storage devices detected by BIOS?

Comment: Yes. It is detected by BIOS.

Comment: I remember trying to install Windows XP on my computer via USB but it installed Windows XP on the USB stick and everything went wrong (it did not detect the hard drive)

Comment: So, very likely, you're mistaken about it being detected by BIOS. What exactly is being detected there that you think is the expected storage device? You may post a photo if you want.

Comment: The hard drive has Windows 10 on it. In the boot menu, one of the boot options says 'Windows Boot Manager"